# Matplotlib dropping data in bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple bar chart I am trying to make in matplotlib. It plots usages over the past few months. The issue I am having is that both the list of months, and the usage for the months is a length of 13. The plot keeps coming out with only 12 bars.

outside of the loop

```
month_names = []
for i in range(13):
    last_month = datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=i)

    # Create string of month name and year...
    text = format(last_month, '%b')
    month_names.append(text)

month_names.reverse()
```

Inside of the loop (I know iterating through a df like this is usually a no-no, but I have specific reasons outside of the scope of this question for doing so)

```
    month_1 = df.at[i, 'cwat01'] if df.at[i, 'cwat01'] != '' else 0
    month_2 = df.at[i, 'cwat02'] if df.at[i, 'cwat02'] != '' else 0
    month_3 = df.at[i, 'cwat03'] if df.at[i, 'cwat03'] != '' else 0
    month_4 = df.at[i, 'cwat04'] if df.at[i, 'cwat04'] != '' else 0
    month_5 = df.at[i, 'cwat05'] if df.at[i, 'cwat05'] != '' else 0
    month_6 = df.at[i, 'cwat06'] if df.at[i, 'cwat06'] != '' else 0
    month_7 = df.at[i, 'cwat07'] if df.at[i, 'cwat07'] != '' else 0
    month_8 = df.at[i, 'cwat08'] if df.at[i, 'cwat08'] != '' else 0
    month_9 = df.at[i, 'cwat09'] if df.at[i, 'cwat09'] != '' else 0
    month_10 = df.at[i, 'cwat10'] if df.at[i, 'cwat10'] != '' else 0
    month_11 = df.at[i, 'cwat11'] if df.at[i, 'cwat11'] != '' else 0
    month_12 = df.at[i, 'cwat12'] if df.at[i, 'cwat12'] != '' else 0
    month_13 = df.at[i, 'cwat13'] if df.at[i, 'cwat13'] != '' else 0
    months = [month_1,
              month_2,
              month_3,
              month_4,
              month_5,
              month_6,
              month_7,
              month_8,
              month_9,
              month_10,
              month_11,
              month_12,
              month_13]
```

The plot (also inside the loop)

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 1.2))






    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 4})
    plt.bar(month_names, months, color='grey', width = .5)

    plt.ylabel('Gallons')
    plt.xlabel('Month')
    plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"


    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.yaxis.grid()
    imgdata = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
    imgdata.seek(0)  # rewind the data
    drawing = svg2rlg(imgdata)
    renderPDF.draw(drawing, the_statement.canvas, 15, 210)
    plt.close()
```

edit: the resulting graph

[image: plot issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the color of the last bar, I found that they were plotting over each other because the month name was the same. This was not the behavior I had expected, but it makes sense in retrospect.

[image]

There is probably a fancy way to fix this, but I simply changed my loop to this

```
month_names = []
for i in range(13):
    last_month = datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=i)

    # Create string of month name and year...
    if i == 0:
        text = format(last_month, ' %b')
    else:
        text = format(last_month, '%b')

    month_names.append(text)

month_names.reverse()
```

Which solved the issue! This was very frustrating to me, so I hope this helps someone

[image]